# XOR and II (concatenation) summation symbols

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators

In Latex, in math mode, if I want to express summation over a range I can use the following expression `\sum_{from}^{to}`. I can do the same for the product.

What is the name of the symbol that does this for XOR or concatenation?

If I do:

```
\oplus_{i=0}^7
```

I don't get the `i=0` and `7` parts below and above the symbol, respectively, but to the right instead, like this:

[image: bulkxor]

With summation (`\sum_{i=0}^7`), that is not the case - they appear below and below in the output:

[image: bulksum]

How can I make XOR, or concatenation (II) larger and with indices below and above the symbol?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want to use `\bigoplus` instead of `\oplus`.

I've never seen concatenation done that way. Addition and XOR are commutative operations so it makes sense to sum over a set (or take the exclusive OR of a set). Concatenation is not like that. I think I would explicitly write out the concatenation. That said, you can use `\bigparallel` from the `stmaryrd` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\newcommand*\concat{\mathbin{\|}}
\begin{document}
\[x_1\concat x_2\concat\dotsb\concat x_n\]
\[\bigparallel_{i=1}^n x_i\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I saw these guys using concatenation summation: http://www.schneier.com/skein.pdf, pages 17,18.

Comment: @axel22: Interesting. I'd never seen that before. Let me update my answer.

Comment: I don’t see why the non-commutativity of the concatenation should disqualify it for this notation. In functional programming, a reduction of character strings via concatenation is a well-defined operation, and defined in the same way as a sum. We’re not talking about *sets* here, we’re talking about (well-ordered) *sequences*.

Comment: @Konrad: Fair enough. One might write `$\sum_{x\in S}x$`. A similar expression would be meaningless for concatenation. That's all I was saying. In this case, you're right that there's a canonical [well order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order) imposed by the indexing.

Answer (score 4):

The usual way to get a larger `\oplus` symbol that takes limits above and below in display math mode is with `\bigoplus`. However this symbol might appear too big; a not-so-large symbol can be obtained by

```
\newcommand{\bigxor}{\mathop{\mathchoice
  {\textstyle\bigoplus}{\textstyle\bigoplus}
  {\scriptstyle\bigoplus}{\scriptscriptstyle\bigoplus}}}
```

For a concatenation big symbol one can do a similar thing:

```
\newcommand{\bigconc}{\mathop{\mathpalette\bigconcinn\relax}}
\newcommand{\bigconcinn}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{$\bigconcchoose#1\bigconcsize|\mkern1mu\bigconcsize|$}}}
\newcommand{\bigconcchoose}[1]{\def\bigconcsize{}%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle
    \let\bigconcsize\Big
  \else
    \ifx#1\textstyle
      \let\bigconcsize\big
    \fi
  \fi#1}
```

Now `\bigconc` will behave like `\sum`:

```
\[ \bigconc_{i=0}^{3} X_{i} \]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `\DeclareMathOperator*` command that defines operator with super/subscripts above/below itself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\OPLUS}{\oplus}
\begin{document}
\[ \OPLUS^a_b \]
\end{document}
```