# Is there a \bigcdot symbol in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, symbols

In my diploma thesis I need to LaTeX a concatenation over a set of sets.

I use the `\cdot` symbol for concatenation of two sets as in `A \cdot B`. (Please correct me if this is a wrong symbol for concatenation).

I would need to type a concatenation over a set of sets, using a `\bigcdot` symbol or an equivalent one.

It should be like when you use the `\bigcup` symbol to do a union over a set of sets, as in `\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_{i}`.

My LaTeX installation, however, does not know about such a symbol and I haven't found a clue on Google search either.

Comment: You can search for symbols in [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) and at [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).

Comment: You can use `\|` for concatenation symbol, here is [an old post discussing it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20680/xor-and-ii-concatenation-summation-symbols).

Comment: I don't think `\cdot` is a good symbol, because it's normally used for multiplication and so it can be ambiguous. There is `\odot` which has also `\bigodot`.

Comment: How about `\bullet`?

Answer (score 7):

Besides what has been said [in this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20680/xor-and-ii-concatenation-summation-symbols). You can also define a new "bigcdot" operator using [`scalerel`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/scalerel) package, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,scalerel}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\Bigcdot}{\scalerel*{\cdot}{\bigodot}}

\begin{document}

\[\Bigcdot_{i=1}^\infty A_i=A_1+A_2+\cdots\]

\end{document}
```

gives you:

[image]

**EDIT:**

I considered some alternative solutions so I will post them here.

As one can see, a problem with the `scalerel` solution is that it stretch the `\cdot` too wide such that the symbol become less appeal (at least to me). So how do we get a smaller dot with bigger "size"? For instance, let's say we want to have the dot in `\bigodot` (we can use `\boldsymbol{\cdot}` for the dot only) without the circle, how do we do it?

Well, there are at least two ways: first, we want to declare this new symbol as a math operator, such that superscript and subscript will go directly above and below it, then we either enclose the bold cdot with a box of total height of `\bigodot`, or we insert a invisible character of the size of `\bigodot` after the bold cdot, as illustrate by the code (both do not need any package other than `amsmath`):

```
\newsavebox\dotbox
\sbox{\dotbox}{\(\displaystyle\bigodot\)}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\bigcdot}{\raisebox{0pt}[\ht\dotbox][\dp\dotbox]{\(\boldsymbol{\cdot}\)}}
```

and

```
\newsavebox\dotbox
\sbox{\dotbox}{\(\displaystyle\bigodot\)}
\newlength{\dotheight}
\setlength{\dotheight}{\ht\dotbox}
\addtolength\dotheight{\dp\dotbox}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\bigcdot}{\boldsymbol{\cdot}\rule[-\dp\dotbox]{0pt}{\dotheight}}
```

That said, we can also redefine other "small" symbol, such as `\bullet` and `\|`, in similar ways. In the end, let's compare the results:

```
\[
\Bigcdot_{i=1}^\infty A_i=\bigccdot_{i=1}^\infty A_i=\bigcdot_{i=1}^\infty A_i=\bigodot_{i=1}^\infty A_i=\sum_{i=1}^\infty A_i
\]
```

[image]